# How can you use Sequelize's Relationships / Validations after starting to use migrations?

Tags: sequelize.js

I've hit the point where I must begin to use Sequelize migrations. Bleh! I've tried as hard as I could to get the initial dataset useful but the time comes for a boy to become a man and learn the great art of running a migration on top of a database.

I'm very new to this and have a very big question. Since the new data structure in my code becomes set in the migrations folder and no longer the models folder, how can I create validations and relationships for my tables? Can I still have use my models folder for this or do I switch completely to the migrations folder?

Answer (score 0):

you should use migrations only first time for declare or change models and properties. After that you should define instance and class methods with associations and validations as much as possible to make "fat model and skinny controller" logic

Therefore you will use both folders =)

Comment: Do you have to create a separate migration to add a new instance method?

Comment: @theptrk If after some time I need to add new ATTRIBUTE to model (aka column in table), I create a separate migration. But methods are defined in model file manually.